# SQL query to get the number of Non Null occurrences in a row for 12 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table where I have Customer ID's and then 12 columns for each month for employee ID's covering that customer.

```
Cust_ID|Jan_Emp_ID|Feb_Emp_ID|Mar_Emp_ID|Apr_Emp_ID|...
-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----
   4       NULL       NULL        9          9
```

For each row being returned I want to get the number of months that customer had an employee covering them..so for instance in the above case it would be 2, since there was no employee covering them in Jan or Feb but there was one in Mar and Apr.

I also need to have this integrated into the current query I am running which does some JOINS from other tables

```
SELECT 
    Clients.Name, Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName as Employee, 
    Segments.SegmentName
FROM
    ClientTable as Clients
LEFT JOIN 
    EmpCoverage as EmpCov ON Clients.Cust_ID = EmpCov.Cust_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    UsersTable as Users ON (Users.User_ID = EmpCov.Jan_Emp_ID OR Users.User_ID = EmpCov.Feb_Emp_ID...)
LEFT JOIN 
    SegmentsTable as Segments ON Clients.Segment_ID = Segments.Segment_ID
WHERE 
    Users.Manager_ID = 4
```

How would I be able to do this for each row and return the count of non-null's in each row for those 12 Emp_Id columns?

Comment: Start by writing the query to count non-nulls and then integrate it into what you already have.  BTW, a properly normalized schema would make this much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I have oversimplified the question, but how about something like this?

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,NonNulls = len(concat(left(Jan_Emp_ID,1)
                            ,left(Feb_Emp_ID,1)
                            ,left(Mar_Emp_ID,1)
                            ,left(Apr_Emp_ID,1)
                            ))
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Cust_ID Jan_Emp_ID  Feb_Emp_ID  Mar_Emp_ID  Apr_Emp_ID  NonNulls
4       NULL        NULL        9           9           2
```

Comment: Very easy solution! Thank You! Works great

Comment: @MattE  my goal is easy.  happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of unpivot to turn your columns into rows and group by the cust_id field and count(val)

```
Cust_ID|Jan_Emp_ID|Feb_Emp_ID|Mar_Emp_ID|Apr_Emp_ID|...
   4       NULL       NULL        9          9

select custid,count(val)
  from table
unpivot(val for x in(Jan_Emp_ID
                    ,Feb_Emp_ID
                    ,Mar_Emp_ID)
        )t
group by custid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider restructuring the table so you don't need to do this.

If not possible you can add an entry into your `SELECT` list as below.

```
SELECT Clients.NAME,
       Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS Employee,
       Segments.SegmentName,
       (SELECT COUNT(c)
        FROM   (VALUES(EmpCov.Jan_Emp_ID),
                      (EmpCov.Feb_Emp_ID),
                      (EmpCov.Mar_Emp_ID),
                      (EmpCov.Apr_Emp_ID) /*todo add other 8 columns*/) V(c))
FROM   ClientTable ....
```

Comment: How would I restructure the table to do this?  Each month the customer can have a different employee assigned to them and this doesn't really have to do with customer information, so they shouldn't be in the customer table. Definitely open to ideas or advice.

Comment: you would need another table of Employee assignments with three columns. EmployeeID, CustomerId and Date. Then insert a row for each assignment - i.e. up to 12 rows inserted per client per year. Then it is a simple join and `count` on that.

Comment: That would work great, but I would need to also have this auto-update when people go in an change the assignments

Comment: yes your application would need to be changed to maintain the new table for these columns not the old one

Comment: Tried that code and got an error "V has more columns than were specified in the column list"

Comment: Did you forget the brackets? They're important